# ng-hide-add and ng-hide-remove not working in angular for transition

Tags: angularjs, controller

/* To view click eye icon to select it.

```
.fadel{ // Css on fadel class
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    top: 0rem;
    left: 12rem;
    height: 5rem;
    max-height: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #DCECFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.40);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #555;
    opacity: 1;
}
.fadel.ng-show-remove { // css to remove and add handle for ng class
    transition-property: display;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    display: none !important;
}
.fadel.ng-show-add {// css to remove and add handle for ng class
    transition-property: display;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    display: none !important;
}
```

// I am doing show and hide via scope in controller but css handler for hide and show is not changing? */

Comment: show  us your html and js code please

Comment: <span class="fadel" ng-class="{showCCRMsg:false}" ng-show="(varOne && varTwo && showCCRMsg)">Thank you </span>

.fadel{
 width: 400px;
 max-width: 400px;
 top: 0rem;
 left: 12rem;
 height: 5rem;
 max-height: 5rem;
 position: absolute;
 display:block;
}
.fadel.ng-show-remove {
 transition: display 2s linear;
 display: none !important;
}
.fadel.ng-show-add {
 transition: display 2s linear;
 display: none !important;
}
var $scope = angular.element(".fadel").scope(); 
$scope.showCCRMsg = true;

Comment: Could you please add it to your question so it is readable?

Comment: It is showing error. Can you please check on this - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dx6olox9vz4s78e/xyz.txt?dl=0

Thanks in advance